# What is the difference between treble and triple?

Tags: verbs, synonyms

- size of the workforce has been trebled.
- size of the workforce has been tripled.

Can they be used interchangeably?Is this an English versus American thing?

I saw trebled used in this [article](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-27239734).

Comment: [The Cambridge Corpus of American English](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/44126/54862) says that Americans strongly prefer "triple" over "treble". As an American, I've never heard "treble" meaning "triple" before now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Triple** and **treble** are [etymological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_%28linguistics%29) twins, that is they have different phonological forms but the same etymological root.

In your example, according to their usage as intransitive verbs [to be or become three times as great in number or amount](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/triple) they are interchangeable.

Yet there are specific contexts in which they have [particular meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_%28disambiguation%29) such as in music, sports, places,
transportation, science and technology, etc. where they cannot be used interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right here:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44125/is-there-a-difference-between-treble-and-triple

Basically what they are saying is that Americans use "triple" as a verb, adjective, and noun, while British and Australians use "treble" as a verb and "triple" as a noun and adjective.

Comment: The only place I routinely see *treble* is in *Treble Clef* where it acts as an adjective...

Comment: That's in American English though. In British English they use treble in cases such as, "I will treble my score on the exam if I study." It means the same as triple.

Comment: When playing darts, my (Irish) boss would try to hit things like the _treble 20_, in which case _treble_ is also used as an adjective.